# Bing Maps v8 hiding/changing icons sometimes requires moving map to refresh

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have a grid with ~300-500 properties in it that has clustering implemented. This grid lets people label the properties with different 'types' and when these 'types' are changed I update the icon in the map if it is not in a cluster or hide it depending on what is selected, also update the clusters to show the number of active items in each cluster.

Everything in the map updates as expected, except sometimes I have to physically move the map around a bit to get the update to get it to refresh. I don't have any events for mousemove or anything like that (only click and rightclick). If I click around all crazy without moving the map no refresh ever occurs, only when the map is click & dragged around.

It isn't the function itself being too slow as I left it there for a few minutes once and nothing happened where as generally if I set it then jiggle ASAP it updates as expected. Is there a function to trigger a refresh on the map manually? Profiling says even to update all items only takes 500ms or so.

In general this is how i set an item to invisible.

```
 pin.setOptions({ visible: false, icon: '' });
```

This is how I set an item to be visible

```
 var normal = icons.normal[type];
 pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: normal.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(normal.width / 2, normal.height / 2) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the pin completely and creating a new pin or is there a big performance hit?

If you set any of the map options using

yourmap.setView({zoom: currentZoomMethod()});

for example, the map 'viewchangestart' event is fired.

My thinking is that the element does not know it has been mutated and needs to be updated. I would check to see if that event is being fired when you update your pushpin.